# Determine $\log(z) = \ln(|z|) + i\arg(z)$ in cartesian form and $z^i$ in polar form.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**

Let $z = -4\sqrt{2} + 4\sqrt{2}i$.

Determine $\log(z) = \ln(|z|) + i\arg(z)$ in cartesian form and $z^i$ in polar form.

---

**Solution**

I have $\log(z) = \ln(8) + i \dfrac{3\pi}{4}$.

However, do not know how to calculate $z^i$.

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my solution for $\log(z)$ and show me how to calculate $z^i$.

Comment: Hint: $\ln(z^i) = i\ln z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $z=8e^{i3\pi/4 +i2k\pi}$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore, the logarithm of $z$ is the multi-valued

$$\log(z)=\log(8)+i(3\pi/4+2k\pi)$$

On the Principal Branch of the logarithm, $k=0$ and $\log(z)=\log(8)+i3\pi/4$.

---

Next, recall that $z^c=e^{c\log(z)}$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
z^i&=e^{i\log(z)}\\\\
&=e^{i(\log(|z|)+i\arg(z))}\\\\
&=e^{-\arg(z)}\cos(\log(|z|))+ie^{-\arg(z)}\sin(\log(|z|))
\end{align}$$

If we choose the principal branch of the logarithm function, then

$$\begin{align}
z^i&=e^{-3\pi/4}(\cos(3\log(2))+i\sin(3\log(2)))\\\\
&=e^{-3\pi/4}\,e^{i3\log(2)}\\\\
&\approx 0.0947802248421549 \angle 119.143224082432^o 
\end{align}$$

Comment: I have $e^{\frac{-3\pi}{4}} \cdot ( \cos(\ln(8)) + i \sin(\ln(8)))$?

Comment: I interpret $\arg(z)=3\pi/4 +2k\pi$ as the multi-valued argument.  In that case, both $\log(z)$ and $z^i$ are also multivalued.

Comment: I don't think I need to have a multivalued solution. Is my solution correct?

Comment: You need to specify a branch for the complex logarithm.  If we choose the Principal Branch, then $\arg(z)=3\pi/4$ and your answer is correct.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I think these problems assume $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: I've edited to provide the solution for the Principal Branch.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I think there is an error some where. I have $\log(z) = \ln(8) + i \dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ for the cartesian coordinates, and $z^i = \dfrac{-3\pi}{4} ( \cos( \ln(8)) + i \sin(\ln(8)))$ as my polar coordinates.

Comment: We have the same result.  Why do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: I am being told that the $\dfrac{-3\pi}{4}$ is incorrect for the polar form.

Comment: You do understand that $\log(8) = 3\log(2)$?

Comment: The polar form is $$\underbrace{e^{-3\pi/4}}_{\text{Magnitude}} \underbrace{e^{i3\log(2)}}_{\text{Phase}}$$

Comment: I am being told to display it in the form *something1* *angle symbol* *something2*.

Comment: Yes.  See my last comment.

Comment: But $\ln(8)$ was accepted as the correct solution for *something2*, but $\dfrac{-3\pi}{4}$ was not accepted as the correct solution for *something1*. So I don't think the exponential form is required. I think they want it in radius, radians form. In this case, $\ln(8)$ was accepted as the correct radians, but $\dfrac{-3\pi}{4}$ was rejected as the radius.

Comment: On the principal branch of the logarithm, $$z^i=(e^{-3\pi/4})\,e^{i\log(8)}$$The first exponential is the magnitude (it is a real number), the second carries the phase (it's magnitude is $1$ and the phase is $\log(8)$).  What is troubling you?

Comment: Since you seem to still have doubts, WolframAlpha gives [the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-4sqrt(2)%2Bi4sqrt(2))%5Ei%3D) $2^{3i}e^{-3\pi/4}$ as an "alternative form."  Noting that $2^{3i}=e^{3i\log(2)}=e^{i\log(8)}$ on the principal branch, it agrees with the answer provided in the solution herein.

Comment: I think the error may lie in their solution rather than ours. I am seeking clarification and will report back ASAP.

Comment: Well, I know that WolframAlph, you, and I have the correct result.

Comment: A magnitude cannot be negative, right? So does our solution still make sense? However, both $\dfrac{-3\pi}{4}$ and $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ seem to produce incorrect results for the magnitude in polar form.

Comment: The magnitude is NOT $-3\pi/4$!  It is $e^{-3\pi/4}\approx 0.0947>0$.  Why do you not understand the difference?

Comment: Doesn't $e^{-3\pi/4} = r = \dfrac{-3\pi}{4}$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  $e^{-3\pi/4}=r\ne -3\pi/4$ is just a number.  You seem confused with something here.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I was confusing concepts. You're absolutely correct. I understand now. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Apolgy for not doing a better job earlier, buy pleased you have it now.